# The UIWebView doesn't display url

Tags: iphone, url, uiwebview

I Load UIWebView using this code :

```
NSString *a=@"http://www.google.com/";
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:a]];
[aWebView loadRequest:theRequest];
```

But nothing is loaded? What I do wrong?

Please help me

Comment: Please post the code where you add aWebView as a subview of some other visible view.

Comment: +1 for nice subliminal advertising

Comment: You should really consider to formulate a question.

Answer (score 0):

try This code may be helped............

```
   UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 690, 750)];
//webView.delegate=self;    
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```