# UIWebView is blank?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am having trouble just showing a browser and setting the URL for it to goto.

Is there a simple example of how to do this and goto www.yahoo.com.

thanks

this is what I have tried so far, but I just have a blank screen:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 340, 480)];  
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"www.yahoo.com"] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 1];  
    [webView loadRequest: request];  
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? Please provide more details

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code... you can try..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.title = @"Yahoo";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com/"];
    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: I have considered here that you have taken navigation controller and a UIWebview in xib file....

Answer (score 0):

[The UIWebView doesn't display url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153012/the-uiwebview-doesnt-display-url)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 690, 750)];
    //webView.delegate=self;    
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your url is prefixed with `http` or `https`. `www.google.com` shows a blank page, but `https://www.google.com` shows up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the delegate methods, make sure shouldStartLoadWithRequest: is set to return YES.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
return YES;
}
```

If it is set to NO you will see a black white page that scrolls in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

All who try to fix this bug. 
First of all there is no bug and this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.de"];
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[uiWebView loadRequest:request];
```

would work very fine but **NOT** in the simulation modus. I tried it works on the real iPhone